# asyn foreach in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, foreach

What I want is to run a code in asynchronous mode to get a faster response (multi-thread).

I have an array like "sources" with feeds and what I want is to get data from each one.

I've thought something like this :

```
$.each(sources, function(key, val) {
    JSON CALL OF EACH SOURCE
}
```

and then group all the results in an array and show them. The problem is that I want the json calls in asynchronous mode due to some of them take some time.

How could I do the 'each' in async mode with jQuery ??

Comment: see this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using deferred objects:

```
// get an array of jqXHR objects - the AJAX calls will
// run in parallel, subject to browser limits on the number
// of concurrent connections to each host
var defs = $.map(sources, function() {
    return $.ajax({ url: this });
});

// when they're all done, invoke this callback
$.when.apply($, defs).done(function() {
    // "arguments" array will contain the result of each AJAX call        
    ...
});
```

To alter the AJAX function so that only the `data` argument is returned, you can use `.pipe()`:

```
var defs = $.map(sources, function() {
    return $.ajax({ url: this }).pipe(function(data, text, jqxhr) {
        return data;  // filtered result 
    });
});
```

Comment: Doing this : 

$.when.apply($, defs).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);

I get something like this:
[
Array[88]
, "success", 
Object
] 
The data is in that array[88], but how could I access to it ?? Sorry for this but Im struggling with this and the answer must be easy

Comment: @themazz you'll get one such entry for each AJAX call - use the `arguments` pseudo-array (per the code) to access them.  Ah, I see, each element also contains the AJAX `textStatus` and `jqXHR` result too.  So to access the nth set of data, use `arguments[n][0]`

Comment: @themazz there's a way to simplify this - I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thank you, your solution gave me an outstanding improvement to my system !

Comment: @themazz glad to have helped :)