# foreach loop wait until each function in each step is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code:

```
jQuery.each(data.modules, function(key, value) {    
       doSomethingLong(value);
})  // end each

function doSomethingLong(value) {
    //some ajax calls
};
```

In this case all the functions doSomethingLong() running at once.

I need to wait until doSomethingLong(value) in each step returns `true` / `false`.

How can i get it in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059000/asyn-foreach-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply try this

```
data.modules.forEach(function(value){
  doSomethingLong(value);
});
```

basically data.modules is an array which you can iterate using `forEach` method.

Comment: What is the difference in obj.forEach and jQuery.each, i think both running functions without waiting on a function finnishing? my problem is in doSomethingLong() when sorting items in another object, but in order how  the function is finnishing calls, not in the order how its initiated.

Comment: @Martin Nothing, no difference. Just the callback handlers arguments are different and its return value.